# Why LazyColumn always seems not showing part of the custom layout view from left and right side?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have code below which I experiment with LazyColumn and Column on CustomLayoutModifier on Text (or can be on anything).

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Text("Normal Column")
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(150.dp)
                .height(128.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
            CustomLayoutText()
        }
        Text("Lazy Column")
        LazyColumn(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(150.dp)
                .height(128.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            item {
                Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
            }
            item {
                CustomLayoutText()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CustomLayoutText() {
    Text("Hello This is a Long text that should fit well",
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(20.dp)
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val placeable =
                    measurable.measure(constraints.offset(180.dp.roundToPx()))
                layout(
                    placeable.width, placeable.height
                ) { placeable.place(0, 0) }
            }
            .background(Color.Gray)
    )
}
```

Both `LazyColumn` and `Column` I have are identical in modifier and arrangement. However, the LazyColumn, you'll notice it will truncate away the left and the right most of the Text. *Note: I experiment with different constraint offsets value, the truncation on thee LazyColumn always happens 60.dp on from the left and the right!*

As you can see in the captured image below

[image]

If I use Inspector Layout to check the view hierarchy, I can still see the Text (for both Column and LazyColumn) at full length. However, part of the Text (for LazyColumn) is not visible somehow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I enter the text longer, looks like the Column also finally cut out. Thought the text seems not truncated, but rather wrapped.

It does look like the length of the Column/LazyColumn is restricted.

[image]

To avoid it being restricted, one can either use `.wrapContentWidth(unbounded = true)` on the modifier for either Column/LazyColumn (thanks to Bach.V for the pointer)

```
modifier = Modifier
    .width(150.dp)
    .height(128.dp)
    .background(Color.Yellow)
    .wrapContentWidth(unbounded = true)
```

Looking at the internal code, it seems that sets the Width constraint to Max. This means we can also manually use Layout to set the constraint as below

```
modifier = Modifier
    .width(150.dp)
    .height(128.dp)
    .background(Color.Yellow)
    .layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints.copy(maxWidth = Int.MAX_VALUE))
        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = constraints.maxHeight
        ) { placeable.place((constraints.maxWidth - placeable.width)/2, 0) }
    }
```